# Is it possible to use a bluetooth-enabled phone as handset?

Tags: bluetooth, smartphone, headset

I'd like to use my mobile phone (Nokia E71) as a handset for incoming calls in Skype/Empathy.

I know this basically means that I have to configure it as a PulseAudio device, but I wasn't able to do that.

Following [a guide](http://discoverylinux.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/bluetooth-audio-con-pulseaudio-in-jaunty-2/) (in Italian, sorry), I installed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth and BlueMan, but the latter sees the phone as a "Smartphone", not allowing me choose other profiles.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the phone is configured to be used as Bluetooth handset.  Typical cellphone profiles include storage devices (access to directories on the cellphone), smartphone, and data links (Tethered internet).  It is unlikely to provide a headset over Bluetooth.

A Bluetooth headset should work well.

Comment: Hi, accepted your answer as I could not find info about which profiles does my phone support, so I think it cannot be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried padevchooser

**Pulseaudio Device Chooser**

[An Ubuntu Forum post about audio device not recognised by pulseaudio](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1301788.html)
the relevant post is by dj-toons 4th post

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have padevchooser, but it doesn't show up the phone. I followed the guide you linked me, but it does not work because in blueman I cannot pair the phone to the PC (the menu item is obscured).

Comment: Is the bluetooth internal or usb dongle? (on your pc/laptop)

Comment: It is internal.